# How to change the fundamental frequency of a sample signal?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, fourier-analysis

So I am dealing with a 60Hz signal that is sampled at 1kHz.   This 60Hz signal has many other harmonics (eg, 120 Hz, 180Hz..... and more).

For some reason, we would like it to be 50Hz.  Could we cheat a little and is there anyway to use the samples that we have, to convert the 60Hz signal downto 50Hz?

Comment: It's probably too late now, but these kinds of questions are answered on https://dsp.stackexchange.com.